# Using Dependency Injection in Xamarin for Mac

Tags: macos, dependency-injection, xamarin

I am creating a simple application with Xamarin for Mac.

I need to provide a decouple architectural elements into solution, but haven't found any information on dependency injection in Xamarin for Mac.

Xamarin.Forms seems to have an IoC NuGet packages, but it is not possible to add Xamarin.Forms into a Xamarin.Mac project, since the current version of Xamarin.Forms (1.2.2) isn't compatible with .Net 4 targeting projects (Xamarin for Mac by default targets .net 4)

Please point me to some information on IoC in Xamarin for Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pretty good article by Rob Gibbens, a Xamarin University instructor, on using IoC containers in Xamarin projects.

[IoC Containers with Xamarin](http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/)

The examples are using Xamarin.iOS for illustrative purposes but I have to imagine that it could work with any of the Xamarin platform projects.

Personally I am a fan of Autofac in general and have played around with it in Xamarin before and it seems to work fine.